# Build image with builctl (buildkit) then run it with docker

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

I'd like to use the latest version of buildkit to build my docker images, because of some bugs in the buildkit version included in the latest release of docker.

Is it possible to build a local version of an image with the buildctl command, and then run this image with `docker run`?

I've tried adding `--output type=image,name=<tag>,push=false` but docker did not find this image. I'd like to avoid pushing this image as it is only used for running some tests. I've managed to export the cache locally with `--export-cache type=local,dest=<folder>` but I'm unsure how to use it from `docker run`.

Alternatively, is it possible to upgrade the buildkit version that docker uses in their released `dind` container?

Comment: I am having the same issue, when I attempt with `push=True` (which I understand to mean push to my local registry) then I get `server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, when using `buildx` with the `docker` driver (which uses also BuildKit), you should be able to use `type=docker` and it will load it into the docker daemon.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#output

> The image exporter writes the build result as an image or a manifest
> list. When using docker driver the image will appear in docker images.
> Optionally, image can be automatically pushed to a registry by
> specifying attributes.
>
> Attribute keys:
>
> ```
> name - name (references) for the new image.
> push - boolean to automatically push the image.
> ```

I'm not sure how `buildctl`/`buildkitd` differ, but when I attempt to use `docker` output, it makes you specify an output file instead of loading it into a daemon.

So instead of loading it directly it's possible to save it to a tarball, then load that into docker.

```
buildctl build --frontend dockerfile.v0 \
  --opt build-arg:VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION \
  --opt context=my-image:$BUILD_VERSION \
  --local context=. \
  --local dockerfile=. \
  --output type=docker,dest=./my-image_$BUILD_VERSION.tar,name=my-image:$BUILD_VERSION

docker load --input my-image.tar
```

There might be a more direct way but that's the only way I could find while trying all the output options from the really limited documentation for `buildkitd`/`buildctl`, as well as trying and failing to create a local image via `docker buildx`.